# Javascript onSelect: function (date) alert()

Tags: javascript

```
var holiDays =[[2018,10,23,'New Years Day'],[2018,10,24,'Pongal'],[2018,10,25,'Christmas Day']];

    $('#calendar').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: setHoliDays,
                onSelect: function (date) {
        alert();       
    }
    });
```

Can I fire the title attribute from the result of the function `setHolidays` in the `alert()`?

```
function setHoliDays(date) {
   for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
     if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
          && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
          && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
        return [true, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
     }
   }
  return [true, ''];
}
```

Comment: Explain what's wrong with your code. At least provide question

Comment: I want to feed the title attribute of every result from the setHolidays function in the alert , which are New Years Day,Pongal and so on and so forth, but the alert function does not allow like this alert(title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```js
var holiDays =[[2018,10,23,'New Years Day'],[2018,10,24,'Pongal'],[2018,10,25,'Christmas Day']];

    $('#calendar').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: setHoliDays,
                onSelect: function (date) {
        getTitle(date)
    }
    });
    
    function setHoliDays(date) {
   for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
     if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
          && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
          && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
        return [true, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
     }
   }
  return [true, ''];
}

function getTitle(date){
var date=new Date(date);
   for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
     if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
          && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
          && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
        alert(holiDays[i][3]);
     }
   }
}
```

```css
.holiday{
background:red;
}
.holiday a{
    background: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<input type="text" id="calendar">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: amazing that's what I really like to do. Thank you very much